# Nesting of forms - JSP, HTML

Tags: java, html, eclipse, forms, jsp

So I have been reading for the last few days on JSP and HTML. I read that it is not possible to have nested forms in HTML.

Does anyone have any indication of how to do this? Is there some JSP code that can aid in this? There is no such thing in my JSP/Java book.

See I have a form, to which there are elements that the user can dynamically add or delete - including new forms. So you can think of it as a hierarchy - I have a parent form, with X (user defined) children, each child can have Y (user defined) children..etc
So when a form is submitted, it creates a new form inside this form - then when the outer most form is submitted, all the details of the forms and subforms are then compounded into a report (I havent decided what I am going to do with this information). All this information is location specific, so the nesting is mandatory.

I have produced a hack, with global variables and some javascript - but it is vulnerable, and most likely will break when the concept of 'users' are added, with sessions etc. So I do not want to use this at all, given that it will be painful to debug.

Thanks,
U.

Answer (score 2):

Your first statement is right; you can't nest forms in HTML.

If you write something that looks like HTML with nested forms, you'll probably find that the behaviour differs between browsers. Some may cut off the form fields after the first `</form>` block, some may submit all the field elements, some may work as you expect.

If you data is hierarchical in nature as your post suggests, then they way I would probably handle it is to have a single `<form>` element with many `<submit>` buttons. You can then choose to only examine the form fields related to the button that the user clicked. e.g. if they click "Child 1", then your JSP just looks at the fields related to "Child 1".

You'll need to make sure that your field names are uniquely named, though - e.g. by some sort of hierarchical naming scheme - e.g. `<input type="text" name="Parent_Child1_name">`

Comment: I agree, and have tried this (mostly) - however what about the rest of my content - surely it is incorrect to have the entire HTML page inside a <form></form> clause?? Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't put your whole HTML page in inside `<form>`/`</form>`, but I don't see a problem with putting the vast majority of your `<body>` in one.

Comment: Yea thanks. It seems to not like this, there is 1 form, with 2 children which contain submit <input>'s & each of these have submit <input>'s - so when I click the child of a child submit, the 1st child closes, as the request for that 1st submit is not submitted again - therefore the 1st child doesnt open, & the 3nd wont...this way seems to hacky - I seriously cant believe that no1 anywhere in the world has not required nested forms. I see it all the time on sites, add new elements to make this page the way you want, by pressing buttons & adding HTML elemnts, which themselves can be added to

Comment: I've seen other programmers doing form manipulation using <iframe> and javascript, Im not sure if this is the road to go down. However is it possible to manipulate and retrieve iframe components using java and jsp? Thanks, U.

Comment: I suspect your problem with your 2 children is at the server side; if you're not using AJAX techniques, then if you click *any* submit button, you'll have to reproduce the whole form, including all the children, not just the one you submitted.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your description I immediately thought of jQuery and JavaScript.  You could dynamically modify the DOM to add and remove HTML elements as needed rather than nesting `<form>` elements.  I'd recommend giving that a try.

Comment: It's even possible to create nested forms in JavaScript. The behaviour of controls inside nested forms is fully defined by HTML5. It's only the HTML (text/html) parser that stops nested forms from being created.

Comment: I havent looked at DOM much, but it is essentially setting out the html documents in a hierarchical nature - i.e. document.parent.textfield etc etc - this will work fundamentally I just havent used enough to know if the creation/deletion of aspects is easy or flexible etc. Thanks for your reply. Appreciate it. U.

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/forms.html#the-form-element specifically says that for form, there are "no form element descendants" - I interpret that as meaning you can't nest forms.

Comment: @gdt - there's two different uses of "can't" here. There's "=impossible", and there's "=not valid". The HTML parser makes it impossible to do it in the text/html mime type; the spec makes it a violation of the content model - i.e. it is not valid. But via JavaScript it is definitely possible. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms for a description of how form/control association works with particular regard to the line that starts "A form-associated element is, by default, associated with its nearest ancestor form element..."

Comment: @Alohci - You're right. It's technically possible and behaviour is well defined in the spec (although you'll still end up with a non-conforming document). Personally, though, I think I'd avoid doing it, I suspect it would be painful to debug.